# Loading data from textfile to a dictionary in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, load

I have a small problem here. Im trying to load a txt file that i have saved eariler while doing a session in my console application. When i load the file. the dictionary appears like this:

```
1111 ['peter']
7777 ['frida']
1337 ['john', 'johnny']
2121 ['peter', 'foppa']
```

the numbers are the keys that are linked to the persons/aliases. When i load it and try to add new aliases my functions cant find the names..

When i add new persons or create aliases to existing persons with an empty dictionary it looks like this instead:

```
1337 killer
1337 murderer
6677 sebastian
```

My add function looks like this:

```
def add(self,name,number):
    p = phonebook(name)
    if number in self.dictList:
        print("nummret finns redan")
    else:
        self.dictList[number] = [p]
        print("Ny person sparad")
```

My alias function looks like this:

```
def alias(self,name,newName,number = None):
    self.checkIfNameExist(name)
    if self.checkIfNameExist(name) == None:
        print("telebok> finns ingen med det namnet")
    else:
        self.isNameMoreThenOne(name)
        if self.isNameMoreThenOne(name) == 1:
            print(self.isNameMoreThenOne(name))
            #getnumber
            number = self.returnNumberFromName(name)
            name = newName
            p = phonebook(name)
            #save object with append
            self.dictList[number].append(p)
            #save object with append
            print("telebok> nytt alias skapat")
        elif self.isNameMoreThenOne(name) > 1:
            if number:
                name = newName
                p = phonebook(name)
                self.dictList[number].append(p)
                print("telebok> nytt alias har skapats")
            else:
                print("Det finns flera med samma namn, skriv in numret")
```

My save to a textfile function looks like this:

```
def save(self,filename):
    f = open(filename,"w")
    for number in self.dictList:
        printNumber = (str(number + ";"))
        f.write(printNumber)
        keys = self.dictList[number]
        for name in keys:
            printName = str(name.name + ";")
            print(printName)
            f.write(printName)
        f.write("\n")
    f.close()
```

And my load function from a textfile looks like this:

```
def load(self,filename):
    dList = {}
    f = open(filename,"r")
    for readLine in f:
        readLine = readLine.split(";")
        number = readLine[0]            
        #print(number)
        nameLength = len(readLine[1:])
        #print(nameLength)
        name = readLine[1:nameLength]
        p = phonebook(name)
        self.dictList[number] = dict()
        #print(name)
        self.dictList[number] = [p]
        print(self.dictList)
    f.close()
```

Everything works when i run the program from the start and do everything step by step adding a new person. creating an alias for a name, creating an alias for an existing alias etc. Something is going completly wrong when i save or load the textfile. My guess is on the load function. Does any of you have any suggestion what i could do instead to read from a textfile and use the program as i do before i save/load from a textfile?

Comment: What is the format of the text file going into your `load` function? What is `self.dictList` and the expected format for the numbers/phonebook objects be stored in the `self.dictList`?

Comment: @Karl I managed to solve it.